# Kummer's transformation of the solution in hypergeometric equation

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

In tranforming the variable from $x$ to $1/x$ in the solution, $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$  of hypergeometric equation of Gauss, $\mathit{i.e.,}$

\begin{equation}
x(1-x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+[c-(a+b+1)x]\frac{dy}{dx}-a\,b\,y=0 \\
\tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

I used the following method.

Firstly, set $x=1/z$. Then \eqref{eq1} becomes,

\begin{equation}
(z-1)\,z^2\,\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+[-(c\,z^2-(a+b+1)z)+2\,z\,(z-1)]\frac{dy}{dz}-a\,b\,y=0 
\tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

Secondly, transformation from $y$ to $w$ is employed using the relation, $y=z^a w$. Then \eqref{eq2} is transformed into,

\begin{equation}
(1-z)z^{a+2}\frac{d^2w}{dz^2}+z^{a+1}[1+a-b-(2+2\,a-c)\,z]\frac{dw}{dz}-a\,(1+a-c)\,z^{a+1}w=0 
\tag{3}\label{eq3}
\end{equation}

When divided by $z^{a+1}$, \eqref{eq3} becomes,

\begin{equation}
(1-z)z\frac{d^2w}{dz^2}+[1+a-b-(2+2\,a-c)\,z]\frac{dw}{dz}-a\,(1+a-c)\,w=0 
\tag{4}\label{eq4}
\end{equation}

which should give the solution form, $z^a_2F_1(a,1+a-c;1+a-b,z)= x^{-a}\,_2F_1(a,1+a-c;1+a-b,1/x)$

According to several textbooks however, the transformed solution is referred to as $(-x)^{-a}\,_2F_1(a,1+a-c;1+a-b,1/x)$.

I would like to know whether the method I used was wrong, and if so, where the factor $(-1)^a$ comes from. Is it something to do with the pole, as $x=0$ becomes singularity. I am not familiar with this concept.

(*)In respone to the first part of Maxim's comment:

If, $x=1/z$, then,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}=-z^2\frac{dy}{dz}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=
\left[
\frac{d}{dz}(-z^2)\frac{dy}{dz}-z^2\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}
\right]\frac{dz}{dx}=z^4\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+2z^3\frac{dy}{dz}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

If you insert these together with $x(1-x)=(z-1)/z^2$, into \eqref{eq1}, it should give \eqref{eq2}.

Second part:I understand that in case considering $z$ as complex number, and assuming
 $z=\vert z \vert e^{i(\theta+2\,n\pi)}$, then $z^\alpha=\vert z \vert^\alpha 
e^{i(\theta\alpha+2\,n\alpha\pi)}$

So, does that mean that $(-)^\alpha$ factor comes from the part, $e^{i(2\,n\alpha\pi)}$?

(*) Responding to the Maxim's comment sent just before:

Yes, you are right. I seem to have forgotten dropping off the fraction command and should have multiplied instead during the copy and paste procedure. It should be as you pointed out,

\begin{equation}
(z-1)z^2\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+[-(c\,z^2-(a+b+1)z)+2\,z\,(z-1)]\frac{dy}{dz}-a\,b\,y=0 
\end{equation}

I have corrected the equation above. Very sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If nobody answers I will work on this; but "I betcha" that it comes from the fact that you're reflecting about x=1, not x=0.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it. As I wrote in my question, I always don't understand when it comes to the problem of path integrals in the complex region. I'll be looking forward to your comments.

Comment: In (2), you implicitly have a new function $Y(z) = y(x)$, the coefficients at $Y''(z)$ and $Y'(z)$ are not correct. Your end result is correct though: if $x^a F(x)$ is a solution of a linear homogeneous ODE, then $(-x)^a F(x)$ is also a solution, since they differ by a (piecewise) constant factor.

Comment: I misread the parentheses in the coefficient at $Y'$, sorry. But, by your own calculation, the coefficient at $Y''$ is $z^2 (z - 1)$. You need some additional conditions to distinguish between $x^a$ and $(-x)^a$, such as the placement of the branch cut in the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I still do not understand specifically how to achieve placing branch cut. I've looked it up in several textbooks and still do not know how it is relevant to the calculation uploaded here. I am very bad in understanding this kind of problem. I would appreciate if you could provide me some fundamental knowledge, if that is OK with you. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, you're ignoring what I wrote. You have $x (1 - x) y''(x) = (z - 1)/z^2 (z^4 Y''(z) + 2 z^3 Y'(z))$, how do you get the $(z - 1)/z^2 Y''(z)$ term? Placing the branch cut is an arbitrary choice. When you only have the ODE, there's no advantage to writing $(-x)^a$ instead of $x^a$. When you want to derive the connection formula $F(x) = F_1(1/x) + F_2(1/x)$, then the choices have to be consistent.

Comment: Regarding the first part of your recent comment above. I have corrected the equation in the text. Please see above. Concerning the second part, are you saying that another solution $F_2$ becomes the one with $(-x)^a? But even if so, when does (-)^a factor come in?